# Edge warning says "'content-type' header charset value should be utf-8"

Tags: utf-8, warnings, compatibility

Edge dev-tools is nice helping out, but some errors I just don't know how to fix.

Apparently there's something wrong with the index.html and two SVG-files. One SVG uses img-tag and the other SVG uses CSS.

I tried among other things adding this to the SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

And for both the html-file and svg-files I tried variations of these

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Also, the last one, why would Edge care if firefox doesn't support a feature?
[image: 'content-type' header charset value should be utf-8]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I bet that Firefox users cares about the web, so they did the tools (or some libraries) which it is used by Edge. Apple and Microsoft (and Google) are relying a lot on open source volunteers. Or maybe they want some interoperability in case they want to change engine (if they will not trust anymore Google). Corporate politics

Comment: IDK if edge is somewhat adequate and interprets terms properly, but `Content-Type header` is not related to your HTML/SVG code at all. It is about your HTTP response header, edge expects server to respond with header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` (and is right, because `ISO-8859-1` is default according to standard, but browsers don't respect it in general). [Header docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

Comment: @SUTerliakov Thanks, I can add that this warning shows regardless of if I load the page from drive or the web.

Comment: There should be somewhere `network` tab in this console - look there for headers of your response. Please add this information to your question (maybe screenshot + text extract of `Content-Type` header, if present).

Comment: @SUTerliakov The screenshot is added. There isn't really an option to select Content-type in Edge.

Comment: It looks like native Firefox console, so could you try clicking on single request (selecting a row)? [like this](https://imgur.com/a/2GgbTrG)

Comment: @SUTerliakov Ok, done. For the SVGs I get a warning that: "Provisional headers are shown. Disable cache to see full headers."

Answer (score 2):

I too spent ages trying to work out this Warning message.

By examining the Network tab in Microsoft Edge's DevTools, I discovered that the Warning message is shown only when data is retrieved from cache, not when it is loaded from file.

I do not know the implications of this. But it is a relief to know that my headers are in fact written correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The error displays that on the actual file that is sent from the server, that the http header `Content-Type` should additionally set the `charset` value.

**To do this depends on which backend server you are using.**

Example in C# AspNetCore (kestrel), when serving static files you could modify the content type provider with these extra mappings:

```cs
// File: Program.cs or Startup.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
...
IApplicationBuilder app;

var contentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
var mappings = contentTypeProvider.Mappings;

// Modify mappings:
mappings[".htm"]  += "; charset=utf-8";
mappings[".html"] += "; charset=utf-8";
mappings[".js"]   += "; charset=utf-8";
mappings[".svg"]  += "; charset=utf-8";
...
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
  ContentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think this is a strange warning, as I also get it on offline files.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue

The browser just wants you to define the [mime type](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_type.asp)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <img src="icon.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></img>
```

Comment: Hmm, weird, I thought that was one of the things we didn't have to do anymore with HTML5. This did not help for my warnings. I tried type="text/html" and content="text/html" in meta-tag. Also I tried in html and body-tags without any luck.

Comment: check if all the links you used in the html have type attribute, the problem isn't the html

Comment: Edge specifies which tags are problematic, and setting the types doesn't change the warnings.

Comment: I guess your case is different then